# What may be the most likely cause for "ORA-00936: missing expression" in the following query generated by SQLAlchemy?

Tags: python, sql, oracle, sqlalchemy

What is the most likely cause of the following error and how can I fix it? I don't understand why SQLAlchemy would generate a query with a missing expression!  And the code works on SQLite but fails on Oracle.  What is wrong with the SQL query below?

This Python code works on SQLite but fails on Oracle 11g:

```
q = (session.query(locomotion_class).join(LocomotionLink, LocomotionLink.parent_id == self.id).filter(LocomotionLink.child_id == locomotion_class.id, LocomotionLink.child_id != self.id))
# locomotion_class is any of the subclasses of Locomotion (in this case Virion)
return session.query(q.exists()).scalar()
```

The above results in the following query:

```
SELECT EXISTS (
    SELECT 1
    FROM locomotion
    JOIN virion ON locomotion.id = virion.id
    JOIN locomotion_link ON locomotion_link.parent_id = 16
    WHERE locomotion_link.child_id = virion.id AND locomotion_link.child_id != 16
) AS anon_1 FROM DUAL
```

It works on SQLite but fails on Oracle 11g with

```
"Internal Server Error: (cx.Oracle.DatabaseError) ORA-00936: missing expression"
```

When I try to run the generated expression in sqlplus it shows asterisk under 6 in "parent_id = 16" (i.e. directly before WHERE) but I cannot see there anything missing.

Comment: I think you should read the notes about "some databases" in https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/13/orm/query.html#sqlalchemy.orm.query.Query.exists

Comment: Thanks, your comment was helpful!

Answer (score 1):

Well, yes - `select exists` is invalid in Oracle as it is to be used as part of the `where` clause, such as

```
SELECT ...
  FROM ...
 WHERE EXISTS
          (SELECT 1
             FROM locomotion
                  JOIN virion ON locomotion.id = virion.id
                  JOIN locomotion_link ON locomotion_link.parent_id = 16
            WHERE     locomotion_link.child_id = virion.id
                  AND locomotion_link.child_id != 16)
```

On the other hand, subquery you wrote suggests that it might be a *column* query returns, e.g.

```
SELECT (SELECT 1
          FROM locomotion
               JOIN virion ON locomotion.id = virion.id
               JOIN locomotion_link ON locomotion_link.parent_id = 16
         WHERE     locomotion_link.child_id = virion.id
               AND locomotion_link.child_id != 16)
          AS anon_1
  FROM DUAL
```

but that's kind of *stupid* as it can be just

```
SELECT 1 AS anon_1
  FROM locomotion
       JOIN virion ON locomotion.id = virion.id
       JOIN locomotion_link ON locomotion_link.parent_id = 16
 WHERE     locomotion_link.child_id = virion.id
       AND locomotion_link.child_id != 16
```

---

What should you do? I have no idea. It depends on what you *want* to do.

Comment: Thanks a lot, your answer very was very helpful!

Answer (score 1):

The syntax

```
SELECT EXISTS ( <a subquery> ) AS anon_1 FROM DUAL
```

is not suitable for Oracle, but prefer using :

```
SELECT 1 FROM DUAL
WHERE EXISTS 
     (
      SELECT 1
        FROM locomotion
        JOIN virion
          ON locomotion.id = virion.id
        JOIN locomotion_link
          ON locomotion_link.parent_id = 16
       WHERE locomotion_link.child_id = virion.id
         AND locomotion_link.child_id != 16
     )
```

Comment: Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1):

*(Posted an answer on behalf of the question author, to move it from the question to the answer space).*

Based on the comment and answers below, I implemented the following fix:

```
return session.query(literal(True)).filter(q.exists()).scalar()
```